# PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm using Java 8, Spring Boot, and PostgreSQL.

I have the following query

```
@Query(value = "select mc from MasterCourse mc " +
            "where mc.institution.guid = :institutionGuid or mc.consortium = true " +
            "and (:searchStr in (mc.tags) " +
            "or lower(mc.name) like concat('%', lower(:searchStr),'%') " +
            "or lower(mc.description) like concat('%', lower(:searchStr),'%') " +
            "or (:searchStr) in (mc.categories) " +
            "or (:searchStr) in (mc.levels)"+
            "or mc.authorGuid in (:authorGuids))"
```

and it is giving me an error `PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.  It does not appear to be any reserved words.

### Edit

So I turned on debug logs and got this executed SQL. It looks like it's not liking my `and (:searchStr in (mc.tags)`.  mc.tags appears to just be returning a (.).  I'm guessing this is because of the fact that tags is a list of objects, not just strings.

I'm trying to match the searchStr on the "name" field of the tags.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
where mastercour0_1_.institution_id=institutio1_.id and 
mastercour0_.id=tags2_.master_course_id and tags2_.tag_id=tag3_.id and mastercour0_.id=categories4_.master_course_id and 
categories4_.category_id=category5_.id and 
mastercour0_.id=levels6_.master_course_id and 
levels6_.level_id=level7_.id and (institutio1_.guid=? or mastercour0_.consortium=true 
and (? in (.)) 
or lower(mastercour0_.name) like ('%'||lower(?)||'%') 
or lower(mastercour0_.description) like ('%'||lower(?)||'%') 
or ? in (.) or ? in (.) or mastercour0_.author_guid in (null))
```

### Edit 2

I resolved this with the following code.  The answer provided on this question partially resolved it by finding a missing space on a line break.  The comments on my question helped point me in the right direction of some joins.

```
@Query("select mc from MasterCourse mc " +
            "left join mc.tags t " +
            "left join mc.categories cat " +
            "left join mc.levels l " +
            "where (mc.institution.guid = :institutionGuid or mc.consortium = true) " +
                "and (CONCAT('%',lower(:searchStr),'%') like lower(t.friendly) " +
                "or CONCAT('%',lower(:searchStr),'%') like lower(mc.name) " +
                "or CONCAT('%',lower(:searchStr),'%') like lower(mc.description) " +
                "or CONCAT('%',lower(:searchStr),'%') like lower(cat.friendly) " +
                "or CONCAT('%',lower(:searchStr),'%') like lower(l.friendly) "+
                "or mc.authorGuid in (:authorGuids))"
    )
```

Comment: It's an Psql Error. So we would need to see the executed sql. Turn on the logs and post the executed sql statement.

Comment: Interesting. We have another query in the system I based this on and has the same concat.  I'll test out some suggested changes and we'll see.  I'll also get the executed SQL when I get back to my desk and update the question.

Comment: @Christian - updated with executed sql and some more info.

Comment: seems like levels and some other fields can't be resolved. I don't think that `? in (.)` has a meaning. You need a join, or maybe it is an embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <s>concat only takes two arguments</s> You can use the `||` operator instead of concat function, but that's personal preference.
2. you're missing a space at the end of the second to the last line `(mc.levels)"+`

Comment: Ugh, thanks for #2, I've been looking at it long enough I didn't notice that... I'll test when I get back to my desk. I'll test #1 as well.

Comment: concat() can take _any_ number of arguments: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5d81a4f127bfc435469ecf861501fa4

Comment: Yeah @a_horse_with_no_name is right I was too lazy to check the actual postgres docs, but I'm guessing you will at least be able to make some headway after fixing that bug. I just got used to adding an extra space on concatenated queries like this even if they weren't required, saves you a lot of stupid debug time.

Comment: CONCAT() and || behave very differently on NULL values: SELECT 'foo' || NULL, CONCAT('foo', NULL);